# Генерация диапазона дат между начальной и конечной (включая их)

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть две даты: `start_date` и `end_date`.

Как мне сгенерировать список дат от начальной до конечной включительно?

---

Например:

```
start_date = 28/07/2018
end_date = 05/08/2018
```

Тогда список получится такой:

> [28/07/2018, 29/07/2018, 30/07/2018, 31/07/2018, 01/08/2018,
>   02/08/2018, 03/08/2018, 04/08/2018, 05/08/2018]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

d1 = date(2018, 8, 13)  # начальная дата
d2 = date(2018, 9, 13)  # конечная дата

delta = d2 - d1         # timedelta
if delta.days<=0:
    print ("Ругаемся и выходим")
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    print(d1 + timedelta(i))
```

Comment: Интересное решение через `days` )

Answer (score 7):

Решение с использованием Pandas:

```
import datetime as DT
import pandas as pd

start_date = DT.datetime(2018, 8, 5)
end_date = DT.datetime(2018, 7, 28)

res = pd.date_range(
    min(start_date, end_date),
    max(start_date, end_date)
).strftime('%d/%m/%Y').tolist()
```

Результат:

```
In [200]: res
Out[200]:
['28/07/2018',
 '29/07/2018',
 '30/07/2018',
 '31/07/2018',
 '01/08/2018',
 '02/08/2018',
 '03/08/2018',
 '04/08/2018',
 '05/08/2018']
```

Comment: Что-то я не удивлен, что в `pandas`'е есть такой метод :)

Answer (score 4):

Вот, что я придумал:

- Определяем минимальную и максимальную даты (защита от дурака)
- Увеличиваем минимальную дату с шагом в 1 день, пока она меньше максимальной

Код:

```
import datetime as DT


def generate_range_dates(start_date, end_date) -> list:
    date_1 = min(start_date, end_date)
    date_2 = max(start_date, end_date)

    # Сразу добавляем стартовую дату
    items = [date_1]

    while date_1 < date_2:
        date_1 += DT.timedelta(days=1)
        items.append(date_1)

    return items


if __name__ == '__main__':
    def d2s(date):
        return date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")

    start_date = DT.date(2018, 8, 5)
    end_date = DT.date(2018, 7, 28)

    items = generate_range_dates(start_date, end_date)
    print(items)  # [datetime.date(2018, 7, 28), datetime.date(2018, 7, 29), ...

    for date in items:
        print(d2s(date))
```

Результат:

```
28/07/2018
29/07/2018
30/07/2018
31/07/2018
01/08/2018
02/08/2018
03/08/2018
04/08/2018
05/08/2018
```

Comment: Таки почему datetime, а не date?

Comment: В той задаче, что решал, получал дату в виде строки, а для `date` не нашел метода `strpdate`, который был у datetime, вот и datetime остался, когда захотел выложить алгоритм :)

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо за замечание, обновил ответ

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

start_date, end_date = '28/07/2018', '05/08/2018'
s, e = list(map(lambda x: int(dt.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y').timestamp()), [start_date, end_date]))
print(list(map(lambda x: dt.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%d/%m/%Y'), range(s, e + 86400, 86400))))
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что тут функциональный стиль сложнее выглядит, это думаю проще выглядеть будет:
`items = [dt.fromtimestamp(x).strftime('%d/%m/%Y') for x in range(s, e + 86400, 86400)]`

Answer (score 0):

Взял из другого форума. Очевидно, лучше пока не видел.

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

start = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
end = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%d/%m/%Y')   


daterange = [(start + timedelta(days=x)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y') for x in range(0, (end-start).days)]
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]