# Выбор даты из диапазона для получения значения

Tags: python-3.x, случайные-числа, datetime

Уважаемые!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как будет правильно прописать получение случайного значения из выбираемого промежутка времени? Допустим есть диапазон дат 01.01.2017 - 01.01.2018, при выборе любой даты из промежутка будет выдаваться рандомное значение (random.randint(0, 100))

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/868140/%d0%93%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d1%85)

Comment: Как связано рандомное значение и промежуток времени? Или никак, и имеется в виду просто некоторое действие при выборе даты в диапазоне?

Comment: @MBo, Здравствуйте, в идеале чтобы программа работала так: Введите дату (вводится дата) и после ввода программа отдает случайное значение (из указанного диапазона).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Похоже, Вы хотите чего-то подобного (ввод 12/12/2012):

```
import random
from datetime import datetime

d1 = datetime.strptime("01/01/2001","%d/%m/%Y")
d3 = datetime.strptime("01/01/2021","%d/%m/%Y")

d2 = datetime.strptime(input(),"%d/%m/%Y")
if (d1 <= d2 <= d3):
    print(random.randint(0, 100))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
from datetime import datetime as DT
from datetime import timedelta

def get_random_date(start, end):
    delta = end - start
    return start + timedelta(random.randint(0, delta.days))

start_dt = DT.strptime('01.01.2017', '%d.%m.%Y')
end_dt = DT.strptime('01.01.2018', '%d.%m.%Y')

for _ in range(10):
    print(get_random_date(start_dt, end_dt))
```

результат:

```
2017-03-30 00:00:00
2017-08-29 00:00:00
2017-01-13 00:00:00
2017-03-25 00:00:00
2017-10-05 00:00:00
2017-02-13 00:00:00
2017-05-24 00:00:00
2017-11-03 00:00:00
2017-02-14 00:00:00
2017-05-13 00:00:00
```